# Using NOT operator in an IF with multiple grep commands

Tags: bash, shell, sh, ksh

I am new to Shell scripting, and am writing a Korn shell script.

My aim is to search for each line in `fileA.txt` in 4 separate files (let's call them `fileA.txt`, `fileB.txt`, `fileC.txt` and `fileD.txt`). I need to print "not found" for the lines from `fileA.txt` that were found in neither of the four files in a separate file.

So I came up with the following If statement. I am trying to combine the 4 grep commands using &&, and doing a logical Not (!) since I only need the lines that were found in neither of the 4 files.

```
for i in $(<fileA.txt);
do
    if !((grep -q $i fileB.txt) && (grep -q $i fileB.txt) && (grep -q $i fileC.txt) && (grep -q $i fileD.txt)); then
        print "$i not found in either of 4 files"
    fi
done
```

I know there's something definitely wrong with the syntax, but being a beginner in shell scripting, I can't figure it out.

Comment: Did you mean to check fileB.txt twice, or did you mean fileA.txt (which wouldn't make much sense, since `i` is by definition going to be found in fileA)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the parentheses. In fact, because you are using `&&`, you don't need 3 separate calls to `grep`.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  if ! grep -q "$i" fileB.txt fileC.txt fileD.txt; then
    print "$i not found in any of the 3 files"
  fi
done < fileA.txt
```

You don't even need the loop; this pattern is covered by the `-f` option:

```
if ! grep -f fileA.txt fileB.txt fileC.txt fileD.txt; then
   ...
fi
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am using a loop because I further need to do something to each line that was found in neither of the other files. And while we are at it, would using a while loop have an advantage over using the for loop in this case?

Comment: They aren't actually the same. `grep -q x B C D` succeeds if x is found in _any_ of the files B C D, but `grep -q x B && grep -q x C && grep -q x D` succeeds only if x is found in _every_ file. However it appears the former is actually what OP wants. OTOH `grep -f A B C D` succeeds if _any_ of the the patterns in A is found in _any_ file.

Comment: Good point. I was going more by the description, so I think the OP wanted `||` instead of `&&` anyway (or `! grep && ! grep && ...`). In that case, `grep -q x B C D` is what the OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't answer the question you asked, and thus violates SO policy, but there's a way to solve your actual problem with awk in one pass that I can't fit in a reasonable comment:

```
 awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} {for(p in a)if($0~p){delete a[p]}} \
   END{for(p in a)print "notfound: ",p}' patternfile data1 data2 data3 etc
```

The `notfound:` is just for clarity, you can change or omit it as desired.

The output values (patterns that were not found in any data file) are not necessarily in the same order as they were in patternfile; if you care about that:

```
 awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]=FNR;next} {for(p in a)if($0~p){delete a[p]}} \
   END{for(p in a)print a[p],p}' patternfile data1 data2 data3 etc | sort -k1n | cut -f2-
 # or in GNU awk v4+ only
 awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]=FNR;next} {for(p in a)if($0~p){delete a[p]}} \
   END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc";for(p in a)print p}' patternfile data1 data2 data3 etc
```

Your question is also ambiguous about 'lines'; do you mean each line in patternfile should occur *as a line* in one of the data files, or can it occur within a line but not necessarily the whole line? Also, are the values in the patternfile only data characters or are any of them special characters that match something different in the data? For example with `grep` defaults as you posted (*or* `awk` with ~ as I have above) if patternfile contains a line `boojum..` that item will be considered found if a data file contains any of the following lines:

```
 boojum..
 boojumXY
 the snark was a boojum!!
```

OTOH the patternfile line `^abc` will match:

```
 abc
 abcdefghi
```

but will NOT match:

```
 ^abc
```

You can get full-line match in `grep` with option `-x`, literal (non-regex) match with `-F`, or both. These can also be achieved in `awk` but differently.